# My new class isn't recognized into activity

Tags: android, class

I want to move all my dialogs into a class and access from there. So I created a new java class:

```
package com.myapp.utils;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.provider.Settings;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import com.myapp.R;

public class dialogs {

  public void showNetworkDialog (Context mContext) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder =
            new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext, R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.warning)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setMessage(R.string.no_network)
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.quit, (dialog, id) ->  ((Activity)mContext).finish())
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.agree, (dialog, id) -> {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }).show();
  }

}
```

I imported my new class into my activity

```
import com.myapp.utils.dialogs;
```

The problem is that my Android Studio not recognize the showNetworkDialog procedure when I try to access with

```
showNetworkDialog(myActivity.this);
```

I do something wrong?

Comment: For class name, you'd better start with capital. https://techterms.com/definition/camelcase

Comment: try `new dialogs().showNetworkDialog(myActivity.this);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create an instance of your `dialogs` class then try to call `method` of this `class` using that `instance`. like following.

```
dialogs dialog = new dialogs() 
dialog.showNetworkDialog(myActivity.this);
```

**OR**

You can make `static function` to avoid creating `instances` like following.

```
 public static void showNetworkDialog (Context mContext) {
   //....
  }
```

Now you can call your `method` using `class name` without creating the `instance`.

```
dialogs.showNetworkDialog(myActivity.this);
```

**Another Approach**

You can create a **singleton class** to `restrict` the `instantiation` of a class to one `object`.

```
// singleton design pattern 
public class Dialogs { 
    private static Dialogs obj; 

   //make the constructor private so that this class cannot be instantiated
    private Dialogs() {} 

    // Only one thread can execute this at a time 
    public static synchronized Dialogs getInstance() { 
        if (obj==null) 
            obj = new Dialogs(); 
        return obj; 
    } 

    public void showNetworkDialog (Context mContext) {
      // your code here
    }
}
```

Now you can call your method from anywhere like following.

```
Dialogs.getInstance().showNetworkDialog(this);
```

Comment: I'm not sure the singleton is necessarily better than the static method here

Comment: I think `singleton` is better.